# Select-Object output Directory path to Variable

Tags: powershell

I have a program that I need to uninstall on a number of systems and unfortunately the way this software is silently uninstalled is by running an exe called "uninstall.exe" this could be in 1 of many directories per system so I have a PowerShell script I'm trying to make work where I look for "Uninstall.exe" in any of the directories it may be located with:

```
get-childitem -recurse -include "uninstall.exe" 'C:\Program Files (x86)\mainoffice-*'
```

This seems to work as the output gives me the full path of the folder where "Uninstall.exe" is located. I will need to then run:

```
uninstall.exe --mode unattended
```

So I think I will need to output the full path where "Uninstall.exe" is located to a variable. I tired to do this with:

```
$uninstalldir = get-childitem -recurse -include "uninstall.exe" 'C:\Program Files (x86)\wwworksmainoffice-*' | Select-Object FullName
```

I can't seem to just get this to output the directory path so I can do something like:

```
$uninstalldir --mode unattended
```

Can anyone try help me understand where I might be going wrong here?

Comment: Change `$uninstalldir --mode unattended` to `& $uninstalldir.FullName --mode unattended`

Comment: Thank you! for my knoldge can you tell me what the leading & in `& $uninstalldir.FullName --mode unattended` is doing?

Comment: See answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

This pipeline:

```
... |Select-Object FullName
```

... will create a new object with a single property `FullName`, so in order to resolve just the string value stored in `FullName` you'd need to dereference it like this:

```
$uninstalldir.FullName
```

This is still just a value expression - it you want PowerShell to *invoke* a string as if it were a command or program, you'll need the `&` call operator:

```
& $uninstalldir.FullName --mode unattended
```

---

Alternatively, you could've used `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` or `ForEach-Object FullName` to get just the raw value of the `FullName` property instead of sticthing it onto a new object:

```
$uninstalldir = Get-ChildItem ... |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
# or 
$uninstalldir = Get-ChildItem ... |ForEach-Object -MemberName FullName
```

At which point the variable itself resolves to the string value:

```
& $uninstalldir --mode unattended
```